# Raspberry PI 4 - 8GM RAM - 64 bit OS aarch64 - easyocr - torch - opencv - illegal instruction

Tags: opencv, ocr, torch, raspberry-pi4, illegal-instruction

I am trying to get easyocr running on a raspberry pi 4 and could use some suggestions or help.  I am using the 64 bit build from May 7th - 2021 (2021-05-07-raspios-buster-arm64.zip).  When I do a fresh OS install, I execute the following commands:

```
sudo vi /etc/dphys-swapfile # change swapfile to 2GB
sudo raspi-config # expand the filesystem to use the entire SD card
sudo apt-get update #
sudo apt-get upgrade #
sudo apt autoremove # The following packages will be REMOVED: python-colorzero
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip # upgrade pip
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip # upgrade pip3
sudo python3 -m pip install numpy --upgrade # upgrade numpy
sudo python3 -m pip install easyocr # install easyocr
```

I open a python3 editor and execute the following commands:

```
import cv2
import torch
import easyocr
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
results = reader.readtext('/home/pi/Downloads/Calibration.bmp')
```

The last command results in an Illegal instruction error.  I figured openCV was the likely culprit so I compiled it from source and tried again.  I got the same error.  I have tried going with a 32 bit build, but torch needs 64 bit to work.  I have tried the same sequence and code through Anaconda on a windows 64 bit machine and it works without issue.

My next two attempts will be to build easyocr and/or torch from source , but I am grasping at straws here.  I am really not sure how to figure out what software is causing the illegal instruction so I can hone in on that package.  I would appreciate any thoughts on what I can do to get more information or thoughts on what things I can try.

Thanks a bunch.

[EDIT]I installed python3-dbg so I could run the application under gdb.  When I do, the error I get is

```
Thread 1 "python3-dbg" received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction. 0x0000ffffe4189fc8 in exec_blas () from 
/home/[USER]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so
```

[EDIT2][I found a git hub repository that creates wheel files (WHL) for those having illegal instruction errors like me.](https://github.com/KumaTea/pytorch-aarch64)  So far it hasn't helped.  I have tried a few, but am going to use a more systematic approach. to see if I can find the right combination.

Comment: Try it on Fedora 34 aarch64. It runs great on my RPi3B+. Reportedly it runs also on RPi4 (despite https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM/Raspberry_Pi says the opposite). Also if you install by pip it is installed from source already.

Comment: @JanKratochvil - I just tried Fedora 34 aarch64 and Ubuntu 20.04 built for Raspberry PI.  I get the same error.